# Resolving a class of and object that conforms to protocol

Tags: swift, reflection, dependency-injection, swinject

I would like to pass an object that conforms to some protocol, and resolve its type for allocation with [Swinject framwork](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) (By dependency injection).

```
protocol IViewModelAware {
    typealias T
    var viewModel : T { get set }
}


class ViewAndViewModelCreator {
    var container : Container

    init(container : Container) {
        self.container = container
    }

    func resolveViewModel<T : IViewModelAware>(controller : T) {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: controller.viewModel)
        let viewModelClassType = mirror.subjectType
        let viewModel = self.container.resolve(viewModelClassType.self) // This line shows error
        controller.viewModel = viewModel
    }

}
```

Error:
Cannot invoke 'resolve' with an argument list of type '(Any.Type)'

How do I get the Class from an object that confirms to protocol, maybe there is another option except reflection?

Comment: You can get the type of the view model class by `controller.viewModel.dynamicType`, which can be passed to `container.resolve` method. What you would like to do is switching `viewModel` instances? Because `viewModel` property is not optional, the code changes the existing `controller.viewModel` instance to a new one resolved by the `container`. I will be able to answer to your question with the context what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @Yoichi this is exactly what I needed. And it didn't have to be optional since it gets injected on Allocation (:

Comment: That's good to hear you it was what you needed. I wrote an official answer to tell the usage of `dynamicType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the type of the view model class from its instance by `controller.viewModel.dynamicType`:

```
func resolveViewModel<T : IViewModelAware>(controller : T) {
    let viewModel = container.resolve(controller.viewModel.dynamicType)
    // ...
}
```